# URL input validation NestJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I am trying an input validation on a website URL. I used the URL decorator but when I don't input any URL it gives me my error message. what should I do to make it accept empty string also?

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @IsUrl(undefined, { message: 'Company URL is not valid.' })
  companyURL: string;
```

Comment: Why do you pass `undefined` as a parameter to `@IsUrl` decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@IsOptional()` class-validator or the `@IsDefined(value: any)`.

**`@IsOptional()`**

> Checks if given value is empty (=== null, === undefined) and if so, ignores all the validators on the property.

**`@IsDefined(value: any)`**

> Checks if value is defined (!== undefined, !== null). This is the only decorator that ignores skipMissingProperties option.

If you need more information about it, check the [documentation about class-validators](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#user-content-validation-decorators)

Answer (score 3):

I had to add @Validateif() to check if it had a value.

```
@ApiProperty()
  @ValidateIf(o => o.  companyUrl
    === 'value')
  @IsString()
  @IsUrl(undefined, { message: 'Company Url is not valid.' })
  companyUrl: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @IsOptional() class-validator to check if the given value is empty or not.

```
@ApiProperty()
@IsOptional()
  @IsString({ message: 'Must be a string!' })
  @IsUrl(undefined, { message: 'Company URL is not valid.' })
  companyURL: string;
```

also you can check more from "https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#usage" or "https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators".